# Taking strings from JSON file, error taking sub-attribute

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to take the image and src strings from each asset in a json file. I can grab the image string but as the src is embedded in "files"[{ }] so my script does not pick it up, producing the error:

ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/user/pinner/src/undefined'
(node:1352316) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

The issue is `` ${asset.id}_src`, __dirname + '/' + asset.src`, `` how do I edit this to take the src string?

pin.js

```
const fs = require('fs').promises
const pinToIpfs = require("./pin-to-ipfs")
const Throttle = require("promise-parallel-throttle")

const assets = require("./assets.json")

async function main() {

    const updated_assets = await Throttle.sync(
        assets.map(asset => async () => {

            const { ipfsLink: image, httpLink: imageLink } = await pinToIpfs(`${asset.id}_image`, __dirname + '/' + asset.image)
            console.log(`[${asset.name}] pinned image to ipfs (${imageLink})`)

            const { ipfsLink: src, httpLink: srcLink } = await pinToIpfs(`${asset.id}_src`, __dirname + '/' + asset.src)
            console.log(`[${asset.name}] pinned src to ipfs (${srcLink})`)

            return {
                ...asset,
                image,
                src
            }
        })
        , { maxInProgress: 1 })

    // write updated assets to assets.json
    await fs.writeFile(__dirname + '/assets.json', JSON.stringify(updated_assets, null, 2))

    console.log('written updates to assets.json')
}

main()
```

assets.json (example of 1 asset)

```
{
    "id": "PowerUp001",
    "image": "images/tools/powerup_thumb.png",
    "mediaType": "image/png",
    "description": "Power Up Upgrade",
    "files": [
      {
        "mediaType": "image/png",
        "src": "images/tools/powerup.png"
      }
    ],
    "rarity": "5"
  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `asset.files` is an array you can't simply use `asset.files.src`, you'll need specify which index of the array you want your `src` from.
So, I'd assume only first item of the array is relevant, in which case use `asset.files[0].src`

Comment: Thanks a lot bud, perfect. You are correct I was initially trying "asset.files.src" but your explanation shows why this was wrong. Have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

Since the `src` property is inside the files array, you must make sure `files` has at least one value:

```js
async function main() {

    const updated_assets = await Throttle.sync(
        assets.map(asset => async () => {

            const { ipfsLink: image, httpLink: imageLink } = await pinToIpfs(`${asset.id}_image`, __dirname + '/' + asset.image)
            console.log(`[${asset.name}] pinned image to ipfs (${imageLink})`)

            const src = asset.files?.[0]?.src;
            if (!src) {
                // here you should handle the case when src is not set
                // you can throw an error or set a default value
            }
            const { ipfsLink: src, httpLink: srcLink } = await pinToIpfs(`${asset.id}_src`, __dirname + '/' + src)
            console.log(`[${asset.name}] pinned src to ipfs (${srcLink})`)

            return {
                ...asset,
                image,
                src
            }
        })
        , { maxInProgress: 1 })

    // write updated assets to assets.json
    await fs.writeFile(__dirname + '/assets.json', JSON.stringify(updated_assets, null, 2))

    console.log('written updates to assets.json')
}
```